# The connection between kink and wavelength

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength

As we know, in EM wave, with the oscilation charge **(for simplicity, charge was moving at constant speed, then accelerated and then continued moving with constant speed again)**, kinks are produced. The funny thing is as the kink moves outward, its length actually increase(the joint vector between the new field line and old field line) due to the fact that new field lines move at a higher speed then old ones.

I wonder what we exactly call a wavelength of wave then. Is it the kink's size ? but if it's kink's size, then it means with just **one** acceleration, kinks size increase and wavelength increases as well which seems to me wrong. one acceleration only should produce one wavelength. So what's the connection between kink and wavelength?

If there's no correlation between kink and wavelength, then wondering what's the wavelength truly is in terms of EM wave?

Comment: What's the Fourier transform of a step function? Does it have a low frequency cutoff?

Answer (score 2):

Waves don't necessarily have a wavelength or frequency. But any wave may be decomposed through Fourier analysis into periodic components that do have a wavelength and frequency.

Comment: then i wonder what's the kink in physics term then ? is it energy or what ?

Comment: It's an electromagnetic pulse, a type of electromagnetic wave. It carries energy and momentum. It has technological uses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-wideband